Trying to get all songs in playlist with over 100 songs using Spotify API
I'm trying to return a list of song names in a specified playlist using the Spotify API. I was able to get it to return over 100 songs, but it is short by a seemingly random amount each time. On one playlist with 222 songs, it only returns 214 songs and on another playlist with 152 songs it only returns 125 songs.
Here's the code that I'm struggling with:
@app.route("/bloom_songs")
def display_songs():

    id = "4AOXvSwX0XGg1cOPZxCa0t"
    # tracks.extend(data.get("items", []))
    lists = display_songs(id)

    return lists  # jsonify(lists)


def get_num_of_songs(id):
    if "access_token" not in session:
        return redirect("/login")

    if datetime.now().timestamp() > session["expires_at"]:
        return redirect("/refresh-token")

    headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {session['access_token']}"}

    response = requests.get(API_BASE_URL + "me/playlists", headers=headers)

    playlists = response.json()

    for playlist in playlists["items"]:
        if playlist["id"] == id:
            total_songs = int(playlist["tracks"]["total"])

    return total_songs


def display_songs(id):

    if "access_token" not in session:
        return redirect("/login")

    if datetime.now().timestamp() > session["expires_at"]:
        return redirect("/refresh-token")

    headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {session['access_token']}"}

    total_songs = get_num_of_songs(id)

    loop_times = 100
    total_requests = math.ceil(total_songs / loop_times)

    song_names = []

    i = 0
    while i < total_requests:
        try:
            response = requests.get(
                f"{API_BASE_URL}playlists/{id}/tracks?limit={loop_times}&offset={i*loop_times}",
                headers=headers,
            )
            data = response.json()

            # Check if the response contains items
            if "items" in data:
                for song in data["items"]:
                    song_names.append(song["track"]["name"])
                i += 1
            else:
                song_names.append("error")
               
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error fetching data: {e}")
            break

    song_names_json = json.dumps(song_names)

    return song_names_json

I tried making the amount of songs I asked for smaller to see if that would increase how precise it is, but it just returned the same results slower. I'm pretty new to programming in general, so sorry if this is a dumb question with an obvious answer, but I couldn't find anything online.

You should check if the JSON response has a "next" attribute. This will be a link that you should GET, which will have a similar response, any more items if there are any and another "next" link. This is called offset-based pagination and is very useful because you can start collecting items from a specific point in the database/playlist instead of starting from the beginning.
You can see the docs to get a playlist's items specify a next attribute that looks like
{
...
"next":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/shows?offset=1&limit=1"
...
} 

